# How to write JQuery callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

My callback function is not working, I want to run `test()` after `configReq()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 configReq($(this).attr('href'), test);
});

var test = function() {
 alert('hi');
};

 function configReq(thisUrl) {
    $('.progress').empty();
    $('.progress').append('<div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width: 0%; display: block;"></div>');            
}
```

Please let me know where i am wrong...?

Comment: `configReq($(this).attr('href'), test);`  this is document and document does not have href attribute.

Comment: and it should be `function configReq(thisUrl, callback) {... callback()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    configReq('Some item', test);
});

function test() {
    console.log('Callback executed');
};

function configReq(thisUrl, callback) {
    console.log('Executing configReq');
    if (callback) callback();
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fKtXR/)**

Comment: I would also prefer to check that varible is a function like `if (callback && jQuery.isFunction(callback)) callback();` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isfunction/

Comment: Well... could do typeof callback == "function"

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a synchronous one.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 configReq($(this).attr('href'));
 test();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     configReq($(this).attr('href'),test);
         });

function configReq(thisUrl,nextFunction) {
    $('.progress').empty();
    $('.progress').append('<div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width: 0%; display: block;"></div>'); 
nextFunction();           
}
```

Comment: You did not used thisUrl in configReq function

Answer (score 2):

To write a function which execute a callback function, you can go like this:

```
function doSomething(arg,callback) {
    // .....
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

---

So your code go like this:

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/z7LDA/1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#foo">click me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){
         configReq($(this).attr('href'), test);
    });
});

var test = function() {
    alert('hi');
};

function configReq(thisUrl,callback) {
    $('.progress').empty();
    $('.progress').append('<div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width: 0%; display: block;"></div>');
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     configReq($(this).attr('href'), function(){
        alert('hi');
     });
    });

     function configReq(thisUrl) {
        $('.progress').empty();
        $('.progress').append('<div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width: 0%; display: block;"></div>');            
    }
```